# Xubuntu 23.04 HDMI Intel iGPU problem

Tags: command-line, nvidia, xubuntu, intel, bios

I have Intel Core i5-13600K with Intel® UHD Graphics 770 iGPU (HDMI) and RTX 4080 (DisplayPort).

If i change default GPU from NVIDIA to Intel iGPU with command: **sudo prime-select intel**, Xubuntu won't boot. I need to change default GPU in BIOS. How to solve this?